# Pyspark Apply function to a column

Tags: python, function, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to apply a function to a column in a pyspark dataframe.
The function is as follows:

```
def remove_space_end(x):
    while True:
        if x[-1] == ' ' or x[-1] == ',':
            x = x[:-1]
        else:
            break
    return x
```

So to apply it to the column 'studios' which is string type

```
udf_remove = udf(lambda x:remove_space_end(x), StringType())

df = df.withColumn("studios",udf_remove(col("studios")))
```

But when I try to use df.show() I obtain an error as follows:

IndexError: string index out of range

How Can I fix it?

Comment: You do not handle the case when `x == ""`. And you can do that directly in pyspark with a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will the following meet your requirements?

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("Java    ", "20000"), ("Python,", "100000"), ("Scala ", "3000")]

rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(*columns)
df = (
    df
    .withColumn(
        "language",
        F.regexp_replace(
            str=F.col("language"),
            pattern="[\s,]*$",
            replacement=""
        )
    )
)
df.show()

+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    Java|      20000|
|  Python|     100000|
|   Scala|       3000|
+--------+-----------+
```

While tempting, udfs are extremely slow and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I would use this pattern instead : `[\s,]*$`